# how can i pass argument in cli and use it in code python if i write in cli pytest --headless it should run the browser without open it

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, fixtures, headless

what can I do in conftest to make it work in test.py if I passed in terminal pytest --headless it should open in this mode if nothing do it with regular mode(show browser)

conftest.py:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--headless", action="store")


@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def name(request):
    firefox_options = FireFoxOptions()
    name_value = request.config.option.headless
    if name_value is None:
        pass
    else:
        firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
        return name_value
```

test.py:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def driver():
    firefox_driver_binary = "./drivers/geckodriver"
    ser_firefox = FirefoxService(firefox_driver_binary)
    firefox_options = FireFoxOptions()
    browser_name = 'firefox'
    if browser_name == "firefox-webdriver":
        driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=ser_firefox)
    elif browser_name == "firefox":
        dc = {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            # "browserVersion": "101.0.1(x64)",
            "platformName": ""
        }
        driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4444", desired_capabilities=dc, 
                                  options=firefox_options)

    else:
        raise Exception("driver doesn't exists")
    yield driver
    driver.close()

def test_title(driver):
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/")
    title = driver.title
    assert title == "Google"
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility to do this would be to access the requests object in the driver fixture.

```
@pytest.fixture()
def driver(request):
    firefox_options = FirefoxOptions()
    if request.config.option.headless is not None:
        firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")

    ...
```

A better and more modular approach would be to decouple the options and the driver fixture.

I did not get why you put your driver fixture into the test class btw.